# Category Permission Implementation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, architecture, implementation

I am a Rails Newbie. Could you please help me What is the best way to implement this?

Lets say I have a Users controller where I ask him what all categories a particular user wants to subscribe to?

Lets assume there are 3 categories, cars, colors & shapes. Lets say the user subscribes to Cars & Shapes.

Cars has tags BMW, Ford, Ferrari, Mercedes etc.
Colors has tags Red, Blue, Green, White etc.
Shapes has tags Triangle, Rectangle, Square etc.

When a particular user writes a post. In the next field I want to ask him which category does the post relate to.. where he chooses either between cars or shapes.

How to make sure if he enters cars category, he should be only allowed to use car related tags only!

May be there are some gems that can help me with this.. but I want to learn to implement.. understand the flow first!

Could you please help me understand how can this be implemented in Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple! Just do a validation on submit. Something like this (pseudo-code)

```
def new_post
  category = params[:category]
  tags = params[:tags]

  allowed_tags = Category.get_tags_for(category)


  # a piece of Ruby magic here: array subtraction!
  tags_he_cant_use = tags - allowed_tags

  if tags_he_cant_use.length > 0
    # render the same page again, with error "You used tags from another category"
  else
    # proceed creating the post
  end
end
```